# Непонятное применение typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

Я студент, и недавно появилось задание написать простейший графический редактор по исходникам препода. В принципе, ничего сложного, но вот только дошел до строчки с `typedef` понеслась) Не очень понятно что делает 7-я строка  `GItem* (factory)();` в коде:

```
public:
    typedef GItem* (Factory)();
private:
struct Registry
{
    char TypeId[20];
    GItem* (factory)();
} GTypes[100];
size_t _types;

GFactory();
GFactory(const GFactory&);
GFactory& operator=(const GFactory& other);

public:

void registerType(const char* typeId, Factory factory);
Factory getFactory(const char* typeId) const;

static GFactory& instance() { static GFactory _instance; return _instance; }
```

Также не вразумлю 17 строку `void registerType(const char* typeId, Factory factory);`, где та же замена применяется. Помогите разобраться. Очень классно будет, если кто-то сможет расшифровать этот блок без `typedef`.

Comment: исправил замечаение

Comment: Игорь Завалов, пожалуйста, в будущем, старайтесь не отклонять правки, как [**эта**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262377), которые улучшают Ваши сообщения. Спасибо.

Comment: я еще не разобрался и наоборот хотел ее одобрить)

Comment: Так и подумал) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В записи `typedef GItem* (Factory)();` объявляется алиас с именем `Factory` для типа функции без аргументов и возвращающей указатель на `GItem`. Далее, в объявлении функции `registerType` используется свойство неявного изменения типа аргумента функции с функции на указатель на функцию. Поэтому тип аргумента `factory` на самом деле `Factory *`. Без `typedef` этот кусок выглядел бы вот так:

```
void registerType(const char* typeId, GItem * ( * factory )(void));
```

Вместо `typedef` в современном c++ следует использовать `using`, кроме того, ситуаций с неявным изменением типа аргумента функции следует категорически избегать и объявить тип аргумента сразу как указатель:

```
using FactoryFunctionPtr = GItem * ( * )(void);
```

Comment: фрагмент GItem * ( * factory )(void) можно заменить на GItem ** factory(void) ? Вообще, эти скобки, обрамляющие имя функции, в данном случае что-то значат?

Comment: @ИгорьЗавалов `factory` - это имя переменной, а не имя функции. Скобочки убирать нельзя, так как они отделяют сигнатуру функции от декларации типа. т.е. с ними первый `*` относится к `GItem` а второй `*` ко всей функции.

Comment: @Игорь Завалов: В исходном примере в `typedef` скобки вокруг `factory` совершенно лишние и ничего не значат. Но если вы добавите `*`, то скобки вокруг `*factory` уже нужны.

Comment: то есть здесь `typedef GItem* (Factory)();` и здесь `GItem* (factory)();` можно скобки в названии опустить, а в тех местах, где `Factory` это `GItem * ( * "название" )(void);` ? И получается, что `GItem * ( * "название" )(void);` это указатель типа GItem на указатель на функцию "название", которая ничего не принимает?

Comment: @ИгорьЗавалов Да, но "название" будет указателем на функцию, которая ничего не принимает и возвращает указатель на `GItem`

Comment: @VTT А есть какое-то равносильное написание этого фрагмента `GItem * ( * "название" )(void);` без скобок с "названием"? Просто действительно не очень понятно такое написание

Comment: @ИгорьЗавалов `FactoryFunctionPtr factory`